# What does "new int[]{some_value}" in java syntax mean

Tags: java

```
public static int getThemeColor(Context context, int attribute, int defaultColor) {
    int themeColor = 0;
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    try {
        Context packageContext = context.createPackageContext(packageName, 0);
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo =
            context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        packageContext.setTheme(applicationInfo.theme);
        Resources.Theme theme = packageContext.getTheme();
        TypedArray ta = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {attribute});
        themeColor = ta.getColor(0, defaultColor);
        ta.recycle();
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return themeColor;
}
```

My question is about this line :

```
TypedArray ta = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {attribute});
```

i.e `new int[] {attribute}`

Comment: It defines int array with attribute being its only element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> new int[] {attribute}
> ```

This initializes a primitive integer array with one element and value set to `attribute`

You can also initialize a primitive integer array using the following methods:

```
int[] intArray = new int[2];
int[] intArray = {4,5};
int[] intArray = new int[]{4,5};
```

Hope this helps.